# MIPS full permutation fail

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm given a task to convert the following code into assembly(MIPS), I can do all the other part but the return part because I basically don't know how to save the value of the previous i.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int symbol[7], array[7];
int n;

void FullArray(int index)
{
    int i;
    if(index>=n)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("%d ",array[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("here4");
        if(symbol[i]==0)
        {
            array[index] = i+1;
            symbol[i]=1;
            FullArray(index+1);
            symbol[i]=0;
        }
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    FullArray(0);
    return 0;
}
```

And here's my MIPS code:

```
.data
    array: .space 28
    symbol:.space 28
    ispace:     .asciiz " "
    ienter:     .asciiz "\n"
.text
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t0, $v0

    move $s0, $t0 #n
    move $s1, $zero #index
    move $s2, $zero #i=0
    move $s5, $zero
    j fullarray

fullarray:
    bge $s1, $s0, print #if index is larger or equal to n, go to print loop
    j always

print:
    move $s2, $zero #i=0
    j print2

print2:
    bge $s2, $s0, always #while i<n

    move $s3, $s2
    add $s3, $s3, $s2
    sll $s3, $s3, 1

    lw $t0, array($s3)

    move $a0, $t0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    la $a0, ispace
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    addi $s2, $s2, 1
    blt $s2, $s0, print2

    la $a0, ienter
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    jr $ra

always:
    move $s2, $zero #i=0
    j always2

always2:
    bge $s2, $s0, end #while i<n

    move $s3, $s2
    add $s3, $s3, $s2
    sll $s3, $s3, 1

    lw $t0, symbol($s3) #load symbol of the current array number
    beq $t0, $zero, storearray #store array value
    addi $s2, $s2, 1 #i++
    blt $s2, $s0, always2
    j end

storearray:
    move $s4, $s1
    add $s4, $s4, $s1
    sll $s4, $s4, 1

    addi $t2, $s2, 1 #set array number to i+1
    sw $t2, array($s4)

    addi $t2, $zero, 1
    sw $t2, symbol($s3) #set the symbol of the current array number to 1

    sub $sp, $sp, 12
    sw $ra, 0($sp)  #save $ra
    sw $s1, 4($sp) #save index
    sw $s2, 8($sp)

    addi $s1, $s1, 1 #index + 1

    jal fullarray

    lw $s1, 4($sp)
    lw $s2, 8($sp)

    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    add $sp, $sp, 12

    move $s4, $s1
    add $s4, $s4, $s1
    sll $s4, $s4, 1

    move $s2, $s1
    move $s3, $s2
    add $s3, $s3, $s2
    sll $s3, $s3, 1

    sw $zero, symbol($s3) #set the symbol of current array number to 0
    addi $s2, $s2, 1 #i++
    blt $s2, $s0, always2
    beq $s1, $zero, end
    jr $ra

end:
```

Example expected output is:

(Input = 4)

1 2 3 4

1 2 4 3

1 3 2 4

1 3 4 2

1 4 2 3

1 4 3 2

2 1 3 4

2 1 4 3

2 3 1 4

2 3 4 1

etc

but my code always returns me with

1 2 3 4

1 2 4 3

1 2 4 3

1 2 4 3

...

1 2 4 3

Please help!

Comment: That C is yours, i.e. did you write it? Or did you receive it? (I mean, the question is, how well you understand how it works)

Comment: that code is given from the question. I didn't write it. I know how it works, at least other than the recursive part

Comment: And do you have to write the MIPS assembly in recursive way, or you can modify the algorithm to avoid recursion? And if you can, which way you want to do it? And something particular not clear about recursion? There's all adage explaining recursion to new programmers: To understand recursion you must first understand recursion. That pretty much sums it up completely. :)

Comment: Understanding your debugger/simulator could help too. Single step the code and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: no I have to write it in recursive way. I know how recursion works but the problem is I don't know how to implement it in MIPS. I've seen resources about MIPS recursion but none was like this. Here I have to save the value of i from index 0, 1, 2, 3 but I don't know how exactly I can do that

Comment: Is there maximum N to be supported defined?

Comment: yes, the maximum of N is 7

Comment: well, your code is not that far from being functional, you overwrite `$s2` by `move $s2, $s1` at one point after going recursive, returning and trying to advance to next symbol. As this looks as MARS/SPIM environment, you can single step over instructions and see yourself how the values in registers and memory evolve. But it will quite tedious, because you write lot of instructions which don't need to be there (no purpose). It's usually simpler to design algorithm well, and write only instructions which have purpose. I will write some answer with more advices, how to code in assembly...

Comment: After having selfish fun with coding my own version... I'm afraid I failed to give you very good answer to your problem. If you may try to put here some specific questions about what is puzzling you about recursion, I will try to answer those too. *"don't know how to save the value of the previous i"* = you did, into stack, and you also restored it successfully, but then you overwrote it one more time. In recursion you usually store values into stack (as you can't tell how deep the recursion will be - if you would store values in registers, you would run out of them with deep-enough recursion)

Comment: Exactly, the recursion of this problem is quite deep so I don't want to store them in registers. But if I don't, what if for example now I go to FullArray(2), i will be 4 before going to FullArray(3) and it will give me i=3 before going to FullArray(4). After returning from FullArray(4), i will be 3 from the first return but when I return again it must be 4, how do I get that value for i?

Comment: Your original code did that... Upon FullArray(2) the `sw $s2, 8($sp)` stored "i=4" into stack memory, and modified `$sp` to point to new "empty" part of stack... FullArray(3) stored new "i=3" to new part of stack memory and updates `$sp` to new empty part... and then FullArray(4) stores it's own "i" to stack memory, etc... until at the deepest level the FullArray just prints the permutation, and starts to track back. After `jal` "finished", you restore your-depth-"i" from your `$sp` part of memory by `lw $s2, 8($sp)`. You lost it later with `move $s2, $s1` = not commented WHY you wrote it.

Comment: Yea I've recheck my code, that move $s2, $s1 is purely accident

Comment: But generally you should try to single-step it in the debugger, to get better idea how it works (although recursion and/or stack usage is little bit more tricky than ordinary code). It's like mentally during runtime: FullArray(FullArray(FullArray(FullArray(FullArray(...))))) You are in the deepest one, and you have `$sp` pointing to lowest point, each `12` bytes upward in memory you would find values of upper level, waiting outside of registers (as registers exist only in single instance, so the deepest-level is using registers, other levels are dormant in memory, waiting for restoration).

Comment: For high performance recursion functions you need to minimize those dormant values in memory, i.e. the less values must survive/persist deeper recursion call, the less space you need in memory to preserve them. That's why my recursive design is rather doing `++a0, jal fullarray, --a0` and preserving `a0` value, than storing `a0` to memory, doing only `++a0`, then restoring it from memory, and letting the deeper call to modify it - to avoid +4 bytes of memory usage for store/restore with deeper recursive calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to try it to write one more time from scratch.

Your current MIPS code is using `s0, s1, ...` as global variables, which is very reasonable for non-recursive code, but recursion is based usually on local/functional way of writing code.

And your bug comes from abusive usage of `s#` registers, many times carelessly adding useless instructions and redundant calculations, until you finally by accident modify something what you did want originally preserve.

Some rough sketch how you can (I will) organize the code:

---

## `main` part

Init `s0 = n`, this one works well as "global variable", no need to change.

But after that try to imitate C-like function call `fullArray(0);`:

```
start:
    # read N from user, set $s0 to N
    ...

    # call recursive function fullarray with argument value 0
    move $a0, $zero  # first argument "index" = 0
    jal fullarray    # call the function (not jump)

    li   $v0,10      # exit syscall
    syscall
```

This part is similar to yours, but you enter `fullarray` by `j` instead of `jal`, so you will have difficult time to terminate the whole code, while the original C algorithm will simply run out of all nested loops and return to `main`, no need for additional test for terminating condition inside `fullarray`.

And you initialize *LOCAL* variables of function before jumping into it. That should already *sound* weird, try to follow "locality" principle when writing source, when things are usually written in the source exactly where they belong / are being used. Local variables should be initialized inside functions (and close to their actual usage, not many lines ahead). And you should use rather the non-preserved `$t#` registers for locals, when you know you will not call some further subroutine, which would modify them.

(this is just convention, as the programmer writing code is responsible for preserving the `$s#` registers, they are physically same registers as `$t#` ones, CPU doesn't make any difference between them ... but experienced MIPS assembly programmer will think about them a bit differently, when reading source)

---

## `fullarray` function overview design

Let's use calling convention following the common one, where `a0` contains argument for function, `$ra` is return address, and function should not modify `$s#` registers.

```c
fullarray:
    if (a0 "index" >= N) { print_array; return; }
    preserve in stack: $ra (return address) and $s1 (will be modified)
    for (s1 : all_possible_symbols) {  // that's range 1..N
        if (symbol s1 is used already) continue;
        mark symbol s1 as used;
        array[a0 "index"] = s1;
        fullarray(index + 1); // <=> ++a0; jal fullarray; --a0;

        // because symbol ("i" variable) is in $s1, it is still valid even here!
        // (if function fullarray() is correct and preserves $s# registers)

        // EDIT: in common convention function is allowed to modify a0,
        // but this design expect it to be preserved! (sort of bug)

        unmark symbol s1 (is unused now);
    } //for(all symbols s1 on position "index")
    restore $ra and $s1 and $sp
    jr $ra
```

("edit" before posting: when implementing, I noticed I already planned in head to preserve also `$a0` for simplicity/performance reasons, but the common calling convention doesn't require that, so this is custom-calling-convention in the end)

---

## `fullarray` function implementation - first try

Makes me sort of wonder, how much code you have already, while it sounds simple. Now I would rewrite this into asm in first version like this:

(note I'm using `byte` arrays for `array` and `symbol`, as max N is only 7, so there's no need to use `word` values, and it simplifies indexing, no need to do *4 to calculate address)

```sh
fullarray:
    # extra requirement for this fullarray function: preserve also $a0!

    # if (a0 "index" >= N) { print_array; return; }
    bge $a0, $s0, print_array

    # preserve in stack: $ra (return address) and $s1 (will be modified)
    addi $sp, $sp, -8
    sw   $ra, 0($sp)  #save return address
    sw   $s1, 4($sp)  #preserve old $s1 value

    # for (s1 : all_possible_symbols) {  // that's range 1..N
    # this will be actually do {} while() loop, because we know N is valid (the main should test input!)
    move $s1, $zero   # s1 = current symbol index, going from zero to N-1 (symbol = index+1)
symbol_loop:
    #here: s0 = N, s1 = symbol index, a0 = array index

    # if (symbol s1 is used already) continue;
    lb   $t0, symbol($s1)
    bnez $t0, symbol_loop_advance

    # mark symbol s1 as used (by N value, any non-zero value is good, N is non-zero and in $s0)
    sb   $s0, symbol($s1)

    # array[a0 "index"] = s1;
    addi $t0, $s1, 1      # t0 = symbol value (= symbol_index+1) (avoiding $s# usage for temporary)
    sb   $t0, array($a0)  # array[a0] = symbol

    # call fullrray(index+1) recursively
    addi $a0, $a0, 1
    jal  fullarray
    addi $a0, $a0, -1

    # unmark symbol s1 (is unused now)
    sb   $zero, symbol($s1)

    # end of for/do_while loop
symbol_loop_advance:
    addi $s1, $s1, 1      # next symbol index
    blt  $s1, $s0, symbol_loop   # while(symbol_index < N);

    # restore $ra and $s1 and $sp ($a0 is also preserved, that's extra requirement)
    lw   $ra, 0($sp)  #restore return address
    lw   $s1, 4($sp)  #restore old $s1 value
    addi $sp, $sp, 8

    # return from function
    jr $ra

print_array:
    # extra requirement for this fullarray function: preserve also $a0!
    #TODO printing (don't modify any $s# register, or $ra)
    jr $ra  # return
```

This is about ~20 pseudo-instructions for core (w/o printing) of "fullarray:" function. Your core part has about ~40 pseudo-instructions. But mostly each instruction should be clearly connected to the original algorithm/intention, with only minimal help-instructions in cases where MIPS assembly doesn't allow for single instruction implementation (like `if (symbol[i])` must first fetch value from memory, then it can test it).

---

## `fullarray` function implementation - improvements suggestions

Now assembly is mostly about performance (sometimes another good reason to write code in assembly is size of code). On MIPS usually size of code affects performance quite directly.

If you will check disassembly of that function, in native MIPS instructions (in MARS: column "Basic" in "Execute" tab after compilation), you will notice the part around `symbol`/`array` memory usage did grow considerably. Loading addresses on MIPS is not trivial, and you have still some spare `$s#` registers, so you can use some for another global value, loading symbol/array address just once, like:

```sh
    # somewhere in main before calling fullarray(0)
    la   $s6, symbol
    la   $s7, array
```

Then inside the function you can reuse that value for addressing:

```sh
    # if (symbol s1 is used already) continue;
    addu $t1, $s6, $s1    # t1 = symbol($s1)
    lb   $t0, ($t1)
    bnez $t0, symbol_loop_advance

    # mark symbol s1 as used (by N value, any non-zero value is good, N is non-zero and in $s0)
    sb   $s0, ($t1)

    # array[a0 "index"] = s1;
    addu $t1, $s7, $a0    # t1 = array($a0)
    addi $t0, $s1, 1      # t0 = symbol value (= symbol_index+1) (avoiding $s# usage for temporary)
    sb   $t0, ($t1)       # array[a0] = symbol
```

This will produce fewer native MIPS instructions = smaller and faster code.

Also as maximum N is 7, you can get rid of `symbol` array completely, and use bit-map stored in register, to mark usage of symbols by particular bit set/unset (MIPS registers are 32 bit big, so this would work easily up to N = 32).

And I would adjust where the +1 happens (symbol index vs symbol on screen), usually in ASM/C programming you want things to start at 0, and end at N-1, so I would generate the permutations in `array` with symbols 0..N-1, and do the +1 fix to human 1..N symbols in the printing part, just reformatting the output.

And if it would be my code, I would rename the symbols to something more meaningful, for example:

```
array = permutation
symbol = used_symbols
fullarray = permutate_position
print = show_permutation
print2 = show_permutation_symbol
...etc...
```

When writing code in programming language, always edit it, until it **reads** good. Imagine you are programmer who didn't write the original source code, but needs to help his co-worker, or fix bug in code of somebody else - read your code with such state of mind, and look what is not very clear, what can be commented better (mostly "intent" what small part of code is supposed to achieve), which names of functions/variables make sense, where the code needs more white space to be more readable, etc.

Investing time during source writing into easy-to-read source will return quickly during debugging and maintenance phase. Usually source is read/edited many times more, than it is written.

---

Plus I would even a bit more aggressively reuse/preserve values in registers, avoiding memory, and avoiding recursion (as it is not needed for this task at all, <strike>it's even making it harder</strike>). And I would end with code like this:

## how it would look written by me

```sh
.eqv MAX_N, 8           # 8 will work at most (BTW, that's ~40k of permutations)

.data

permutation:    .space MAX_N
# must follow in memory the permutation array directly, at +MAX_N offset, do not move it
symbol_masks:   .space MAX_N     # current symbol mask per position in "permutation" array

input_N_prompt: .asciiz "Enter N (permutation size, 1..7): "

.text

start:
    li   $v0, 4
    la   $a0, input_N_prompt
    syscall             # display input prompt
    li   $v0, 5
    syscall             # read integer from user
    # validate N (1 <= N <= MAX_N)
    blez $v0, start
    bgt  $v0, MAX_N, start

    # initialize global "variables"
    move $s0, $v0       # s0 = N
    move $s1, $zero     # s1 = symbols used (none) = bitmask, each symbol has one bit
    la   $s2, permutation # s2 = permutation.begin() address
    addu $s3, $s2, $s0  # s3 = permutation.end() address
    addi $s4, $zero, 1  # s4 = 1
    move $t7, $s2       # t7 = current position in permutation (address)

symbol_loop_init_position:
    # initialize current (position) symbol to 0 with mask 0x01
    sb   $zero, ($t7)
    sb   $s4, MAX_N($t7)

symbol_loop:            # loops through all symbols for current position $t7
    # will try if symbol at current position is valid
    lb   $t0, MAX_N($t7)  # load bit mask of current symbol
    and  $at, $t0, $s1    # check usage
    beq  $at, $t0, advance_to_next_symbol # when used, advance to next symbol

    # valid symbol in permutation found, mark symbol as used
    or   $s1, $s1, $t0
    # advance to next position
    addi $t7, $t7, 1
    bne  $t7, $s3, symbol_loop_init_position

    # permutation is complete, display it
    jal  print_permutation
    # after print continue with "symbol_loop_retreat" logic (back to valid position)

symbol_loop_retreat:    # current position "exhausted" in search (or printed), retreat
    beq  $t7, $s2, all_permutations_printed  # retreating from first position => end
    addi $t7, $t7, -1   # retreat one position back
    lb   $at, MAX_N($t7)# load bitmask of current symbol at current position
    xor  $s1, $s1, $at  # unmark the currently used symbol
    # and try next symbol for new (previous) current position

advance_to_next_symbol:
    lb   $at, ($t7)
    addi $at, $at, 1    # advance to next symbol value
    beq  $at, $s0, symbol_loop_retreat # symbol == N -> retreat to previous position
    sb   $at, ($t7)     # store next symbol into permutation
    lb   $at, MAX_N($t7)
    sll  $at, $at, 1    # advance also symbol bitmask
    sb   $at, MAX_N($t7)
    j    symbol_loop    # and try it in permutation, if the new symbol is valid

all_permutations_printed:
    # terminate execution
    li   $v0, 10
    syscall

# not a general subroutine, using known registers heavily, modifies only v0, a0 (t7 = s3 at end (again))
print_permutation:
    move $t7, $s2        # permutation.begin() address for display loop
print_permutation_loop:
    # print one symbol from permutation
    move $v0, $s4        # v0 = 1 (print integer)
    lb   $a0, ($t7)      # load permutation symbol (in 0..N-1 value)
    add  $a0, $a0, $s4   # do +1 to make it "human" formatted 1..N value
    syscall
    # print single space character
    li   $v0, 11
    li   $a0, ' '
    syscall
    # loop until all symbols were printed
    addi $t7, $t7, 1     # ++address of current symbol
    bne  $t7, $s3, print_permutation_loop
    # print newline character
    li   $v0, 11
    li   $a0, '\n'
    syscall
    jr   $ra             # return
```

After writing it, actually the control flow of non-recursive version is much more tricky to follow, took quite some time to write it, and thankfully worked on first try, so I didn't have to debug it (but that's why it took lot of time to write it, about ~2h probably, until I managed to clean it up enough that it made sense and fit together nicely).

But from a performance point of view, this is about 200B long code, yours is about 350B. Also total amount of executed instructions will be much lower, as I keep storing/restoring in memory only symbol a its usage-bit-mask, not touching stack. (although the output to console with "print integer" will make it actually similarly slow as your original code... if I would consider the "print" part of the task - I consider only the permutation generator the main focus - I would change the permutation generator to generate directly whole line string, mutating the ASCII letters themselves, not integer elements, that would remove need of "print integer" calls, which are by far the most complicated code being executed (unfortunately hidden inside MARS simulator implementation, not created in MIPS assembly, so you can't take a peek inside in debugger to see how much effort it takes to print integer value as string).

It can be still a bit shortened by few bytes, but I tried to keep it somewhat readable, so you have actual chance to read through it, and understand how it works. It should be somewhat tricky, hopefully using several concepts which you maybe don't know, or haven't used yet (for example bit-set to store/check which symbols are used/unused, using memory addresses instead of index values for main loop, etc...). Of course it's not recursive, so you can't submit that as solution to your class... Fix yours, it's not that difficult together with my "first try" example, and debugger.

(one more thing.. about `$at` register usage... rather don't do that, if you are not 100% sure how to do that safely, basically you must know which instructions are native MIPS and which are pseudo-instructions, as those often use `$at` register for intermediate calculations, so a code using `$at` for some value will then break upon using some pseudo-instruction unexpectedly ... I'm using `$at` as partial fun challenge, to make it somewhat more complex, I would not in some serious production code.)

---

And one more thing about your original code, which I forgot to mention, but it shows you understand the concept, but need to practice to get more skill (don't worry, it comes with amount of code you write, it takes time):

Code like this:

```
    move $s3, $s2
    add $s3, $s3, $s2
    sll $s3, $s3, 1
```

Is essentially doing s3 = s2*4, but in complex way: s3 = s2, s3 += s2 (that's s2*2), s3 <<= 1 (s3 = s3*2).

It can be done with single instruction on MIPS:

```
    sll  $s3, $s2, 2  # s3 = s2 * 4 (by shifting s2 value 2 bits left)
```

This was partially responsible for your main bug, as you kept using several registers for this, until you did change also "i" by accident (when you can simply set up one temporary register by single instruction).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It's way shorter than I thought it would be. Again, thank you! I'll try to understand your code